# Can't get PHP script to write user input to text file

Tags: php, html, file, email, post

I cannot get this simple `PHP` script to grab the data from the `HTML` form. The script throws this warning:

> (Notice: Use of undefined constant ’email’ - assumed '’email’' in
>   /absolute/fullpath/godaddy/frustration/html/mail.php on line 5)

**Longer explanation:** I am writing this simple `PHP` script for my buddy’s website. It is supposed to collect the email address and write it to a text file. I decided to go this route instead of utilizing any type of database. I have the `email.txt` file and `PHP` script both on the root directory of the webserver. We’re using `GoDaddy` to host the site. I made sure `GoDaddy` had `PHP` enabled and that no restrictive settings were present.

I changed the permissions of both the script and the text file to `666`. I’ve concluded that the script doesn’t grab the data that is being posted from the `HTML` form. I came to this conclusion because I tested the `fwrite` function and it easily wrote to the text file `(email.txt)` without a hiccup.

I’ve spent only a few hours over the past two weeks trying to complete this, but I feel like I have exhausted all of my options. I’ve searched far and wide through Google and noticed other people with similar issues. However, they fixed their issue by adding full-paths for the text file, changing permissions, etc.

Whenever I input an email address into the textbox and hit submit nothing is written to the `email.txt` file, just an empty text file.

Thank you in advance for any feedback or help. It’s much appreciated!

```
<form id="emaillist" name="email" method="post" action="mail.php">
<label for="mailList"></label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
<input type="submit" name="submitMail" id="submitMail" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); // show errors
error_reporting(-1); // of all levels
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); // PHP will complain about on this error level
$emailaddr = $_POST[’email’];
$fp = fopen('/full/path/totextfile/html/email.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $emailaddr);
fclose($fp);
echo 'Thank you!';
phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: hello! If Pupil's answer, below fixes your problem please tick the tick next to the anwser to show it's the one that worked! cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct:

```
$emailaddr = $_POST[’email’]; // back ticks are used to enclose, incorrect.
```

To:

```
$emailaddr = $_POST['email']; // single quotes are used to enclose, correct.
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I appreciate it!  I have no idea how the back ticks even got there. Thanks again!